# Issue With Configuring AppSetting Services c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to load the app settings file from my program.cs file as below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { Setup(); }

private static IServiceProvider Setup()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        //configuration
        var config = SetupConfigurationServices(services);

        //app services
        ConfigureApplicationServices(services, config);

        services.AddSingleton<IStartup, Startup>();
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

private static IConfigurationRoot SetupConfigurationServices(ServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

```
private static void ConfigureApplicationServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            //configuration
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("App"));

        }
```

Here is my appsettings file:

```
{
  "App": {
    "AppName": "Test",
    "Version": "0.1",
    "Environment": "local"
  }
}
```

Below is the AppSettings.cs class

```
public class AppSettings
    {
        public string AppName{ get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Environment { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem I am facing here is from the 'ConfigureApplicationServices' method, when using the below piece of code
services.Configure(configuration.GetSection("App"));

I keep getting error as below:

```
'Cannot convert from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action.TestProcessor.Domain.AppSettings>'
```

I am not sure what wrong I have been doing here. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use services.Configure as below:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(setting =>
{
    Configuration.GetSection("App").Bind(setting);
});
```